# I am getting x-csrf-Token error from the API written in SAP ABAP in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, abap, csrf-token

I'm trying to make http post in flutter using API written through SAP ABAP. I am using x-csrf-Token and when I debug the data I sent, I get a 403 error because the wrong token is received. By fetching, I directly retrieve the x-csrf-Token value and send the value I retrieved. However, it gives a 403 error. How can I solve this?

```
  Future<void> postData() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "Bukrs": "ABC",
      "Hbkid": "12345",
      "Kunnr": "67890",
      "Name1": "Örnek İsim",
      "Waers": "USD",
      "Dlimt": "10000",
      "Rlimt": "5000",
      "Klimt": "7500",
      "Blimt": "3000"
    };
    print( jsonEncode(data));
    String csrfToken ='';
    String cookie ='';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    final String apiUrl2 =
        "url2)?\$format=json";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl2),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Authorization': basicAuth,
          'x-csrf-token': 'fetch',
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(json.decode(response.body));
        csrfToken = response.headers['x-csrf-token']!;
        cookie = response.headers['set-cookie']!;
        print("x-csrf-token: $csrfToken");
        print("\n *----------------------cookie: $cookie");
      } else {
        print("HATAAAA: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Hata oluştu: $e");
    }

    String basicAuth2 = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    final String apiUrl =
        "url";
    print(csrfToken);
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers:{
          'Authorization': basicAuth2,
          'x-csrf-token': csrfToken,
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Cookie': cookie,
        },
        body: jsonEncode(data),
      );
      print('Gönderilen Headerlar: ${response.request!.headers}');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Veri başarıyla gönderildi");
      } else {
        print("Veri gönderme başarısız: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Hata oluştu: $e");
    }
  }
```

Postman header:
[image]

Comment: Use Postman or whatever tool to make it work. After that, just reproduce the same HTTP request by program.

Comment: I checked it from Postman. It works perfectly there. I added the headers image.

Comment: Obviously at least one of the two HTTP requests that you send is different from the ones you send through Postman. You must check rigorously that every header field is exactly the same.

Comment: I checked again and it's exactly the same.

Comment: I see that your Postman uses `Connection: keep-alive` but not your program. So I guess that the point of your question should be "how to compare HTTP requests between Postman and other tool". Please post all evidence in the question how you compare. Especially, mention whether you used Fiddler to trace the outbound HTTP requests or another tool? Also better post the full Postman HTTP requests, not just a partial screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I received the cookies I received when purchasing tokens. I sent it in the post process.